# How to fix "Key Error :'not in index' " error in Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: python-3.x

The code is to plot the colored graph of the total number of cases in red and recovered cases in green. 
There is a key error of not in the index, I checked the spelling and also the syntax, Stil can't find the solution.

```
#Visulizating Data using Seaborn

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 8))
data = df_full[['Name of the State / UT', 'Total Confirmed Cases (Indian National)', 'Recovered', 
'Deaths']]
data.sort_values('Total cases', ascending=False, inplace=True)
sns.set_color_codes("pastel")
sns.barplot(x="Total Confirmed Cases (Indian National)", y="Name of the State / UT", 
 data=data,lable="Total", color="r")

sns.set_color_codes("muted")
sns.barplot(x="Recovred", y="Name of the State / UT", data=data,label="Reccovered", color="g")

#ADD a legend and informative axis label
ax.legend(ncol=2, loc="lower right", frameon=True)
ax.set(xlim=(0, 35), ylabel="", xlabel="Cases")
sns.despine(left=True, bottom=True)

**ERROR**
KeyError: "['Name of the State / UT'] not in index"
```

Comment: You'll probably need to provide some more details, like an example of `df_full` and the whole traceback of your error

Comment: Please give us the result of `df_full.columns`.

Comment: ->India_cord = pd.read_excel('Indian Coordinates.xlsx') ->df_full = pd.merge(India_cord, df, on='Name of State / UT')

Comment: The result of df_full.columns is : Index(['Name of State / UT', 'Latitude', 'Longitude', 'Sr. No.', 'Total Cases',
       'Recovered', 'Deaths'],
      dtype='object')

Comment: Did you tried to escape the slash with a backslash?